# When reading file with Java Scanner, it hangs after the last line has been processed

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

My method is able to read all the lines of the file but then it gets stuck at the last line and never reaches `scanner.close()` and onwards. I'm not sure why? I invoke `scanner.nextLine()` so surely it should detect this and `scanner.hasNextLine()` should return false when the file ends. Is there a quick fix that I have overlooked here?

```
private int[] GetNumberOfRowsAndColumns(BufferedReader br) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(br);
    String line = "";
    int column_max = 0;
    int total_rows = 0;
    int[] result = new int[1];

    try {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (line.length() > column_max) {
                column_max = line.length();
            }
            total_rows++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    scanner.close();
    result[0] = column_max;
    result[1] = total_rows;

    return result;
}
```

The file in question:

```
+++++++++++++++++
+0A             +
+AA          ++++
+               +
+            ++A+
+             +a+
+++++++++++++++++
```

EDIT:

```
public SearchClient(BufferedReader serverMessages) throws Exception {
    Map<Character, String> colors = new HashMap<Character, String>();
    String line, color;

    int agentCol = -1, agentRow = -1;
    int colorLines = 0, levelLines = 0;

    // Read lines specifying colors
    while ((line = serverMessages.readLine())
            .matches("^[a-z]+:\\s*[0-9A-Z](,\\s*[0-9A-Z])*\\s*$")) {
        line = line.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        String[] colonSplit = line.split(":");
        color = colonSplit[0].trim();

        for (String id : colonSplit[1].split(",")) {
            colors.put(id.trim().charAt(0), color);
        }
        colorLines++;
    }

    if (colorLines > 0) {
        error("Box colors not supported");
    }
    int[] result = getNumberOfRowsAndColumns(serverMessages);
    System.err.println("MAX COLUMNS = " + result[0]);
    System.err.println("MAX ROWS = " + result[1]);

    initialState = new Node(null);

    while (!line.equals("")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            char chr = line.charAt(i);
            if ('+' == chr) { // Walls
                initialState.walls[levelLines][i] = true;
            } else if ('0' <= chr && chr <= '9') { // Agents
                if (agentCol != -1 || agentRow != -1) {
                    error("Not a single agent level");
                }
                initialState.agentRow = levelLines;
                initialState.agentCol = i;
            } else if ('A' <= chr && chr <= 'Z') { // Boxes
                initialState.boxes[levelLines][i] = chr;
            } else if ('a' <= chr && chr <= 'z') { // Goal cells
                initialState.goals[levelLines][i] = chr;
            }
        }
        line = serverMessages.readLine();
        levelLines++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation for `hasNextLine()` says "Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner. **This method may block while waiting for input.** The scanner does not advance past any input."

Answer (score 2):

By convention, Java methods start with a lower case letter. Next, your array can only hold one value (length of 1) and you don't need a `Scanner` (use your `BufferedReader`). Finally, you can make an anonymous array. Something like,

```
private int[] getNumberOfRowsAndColumns(BufferedReader br) {
    int column_max = 0;
    int total_rows = 0;

    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // if (line.length() > column_max) {
            //  column_max = line.length();
            // }
            column_max = Math.max(column_max, line.length());
            total_rows++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return new int[] { column_max, total_rows };
}
```

Comment: Because [`Scanner.hasNextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) *may block while waiting for input.*

Comment: Since it does that, how can that method ever be useful?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I hope you don't mind that I added a line towards the end of your method. But I'm not able to reach that output line. I've tried placing it earlier (e.g. in the while loop) where it does indeed go through all lines of the file. But it's the same problem as before, it doesn't proceed to do anything after that?

Comment: @D.Singh The code I've posted will stop after reading every line in a file. Please post your File and explain how you're calling it.

Comment: @DanielKaplan If you back it with a `InputStreamReader` it can work, if you back it with a `BufferedReader` it isn't very useful. Character vs binary io.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch In another part of my program I'm calling the above method and I simply want to look at the result of the method i.e. the int array. But the program never returns from the method, it gets stuck in there. The file is 7 lines of simple characters. I'll edit my question to include the file. 
Your code does indeed read the file, but it doesn't seem to exit the while loop. Maybe it's due to the file, I don't know.

Comment: @D.Singh Now post the other part of your program (that calls this method).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Has it got something to do with how I'm using the bufferedReader before calling the method?

Comment: @D.Singh Yes. You can't share the `Reader` instance like that (it doesn't reset).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ok thank you. In the context of the code that I have provided do you have a better suggestion on how to figure out the number of rows and columns before setting initialState = new Node(null); ?

Comment: First, count the rows and columns (with one reader) and pass those numbers into the second method (along with a second reader).